# Examples of elegant, concise code in Clojure

Tags: coding-style, clojure

I'm looking for enlightening examples of concise and elegant code in Clojure - mainly to learn new techniques and improve my own style.

Can you offer any nuggets of pure genius?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically everything Nurullah Akkaya posts:

http://nakkaya.com/

Definitely some of the most imaginative Clojure examples around. Don't blame me for all the time you'll spend reading his stuff... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This is fun:

```
(= (sort "eleven plus two") (sort "twelve plus one"))
```

This evaluates to true because "eleven plus two" is an anagram of "twelve plus one"

More fun than useful.

Answer (score 5):

[Ring](http://github.com/mmcgrana/ring) is an excellent example - very idiomatic and elegant code there.

Answer (score 4):

There are loads at [learnclojure on twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/learnclojure). :-)